# After moving an item in kanban board , the item index is not updated

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend, react-dnd

I am building a Kanban board in React DND for learning react.
Each board has a list, and each item is assigned an index at render time.

I want the state to be updated with each drag-drop, but after I activate setState, the index is not updated, so the operation does not work after the first time.

I can confirm that setState works and updates the state.
My understanding is that the index is re-rendered and updated, but only the index is not updated.
I would be grateful if you could let me know what you notice.

Board.tsx

```
  return (
    <TaskWrapper ref={drop}>
      <BoardName>{props.groupName}</BoardName>
      {props.taskList.map((taskItem, i) => {
        return (
          <Draggable
            key={taskItem.id}
            task={taskItem}
            index={props.firstIndex + i}
            firstIndex={props.firstIndex}
            swapTaskItem={props.swapTaskItem}
          >
            <TaskCard
              task={taskItem}
              deleteTask={props.deleteTask}
              editTask={props.editTask}
              parentRef={ref}
            />
          </Draggable>
        );
      })}
```

Draggable.tsx

```
function Draggable(props: Props) {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [{ isDragging, canDrag }, drag] = useDrag(() => ({
    type: ItemTypes.TASKITEM,
    // item: { ...props.task, index: props.index },
    item: () => {
      debugger;
      return { ...props.task, index: props.index };
    },
    isDragging: (monitor) => {
      return monitor.getItem().id === props.task.id;
    },
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
      canDrag: monitor.canDrag(),
    }),
  }));

  const [, drop] = useDrop({
    accept: ItemTypes.TASKITEM,
    hover(dragItem: TaskItemForDrag, monitor) {
      if (!ref.current) return;

      if (dragItem.id === props.task.id) return;
      debugger;

      const dragIndex = dragItem.index - props.firstIndex;
      const hoverIndex = props.index - props.firstIndex;
      if (!dragIndex || dragIndex === hoverIndex) return;

      if (props.task.group === dragItem.group) {
        // Determine rectangle on screen
        const hoverRect = ref.current?.getBoundingClientRect();

        // Determine mouse position
        const mousePosition = monitor.getClientOffset();
        const hoverMiddleY = (hoverRect!.bottom - hoverRect!.top) / 2;
        const hoverClientY = mousePosition!.y - hoverRect!.top;

        if (!mousePosition) return;
        if (dragIndex < hoverIndex && hoverClientY < hoverMiddleY) return;
        if (dragIndex > hoverIndex && hoverClientY > hoverMiddleY * 1.5) return;
      }

      props.swapTaskItem(dragItem, dragIndex, hoverIndex, props.task.group);
      dragItem.index = props.index;
    },
  });
  drag(drop(ref));

  return <div ref={ref}>{props.children}</div>;
}

export default Draggable;
```

useTaskList

```
  const swapTaskItem = useCallback(
    (
      dragItem: TaskItem,
      dragIndex: number,
      targetIndex: number,
      hoverGroup: string
    ) => {
      setTaskCards((prevState: TaskColumn[]) => {
        const sourceCard = find(prevState, { groupName: dragItem.group });
        const targetCard = find(prevState, { groupName: hoverGroup });

        if (targetCard) {
          const dragItem = targetCard.list[dragIndex];
          const newList = targetCard.list.filter(
            (item, idx) => item !== null && idx !== dragIndex
          );
          if (!dragItem) return prevState;
          newList.splice(targetIndex, 0, dragItem);

          const updatedItems = { ...targetCard, list: newList };
          debugger;

          return prevState.map((item) =>
            item.groupName === updatedItems.groupName ? updatedItems : item
          );
        }
        return prevState;
      });
    },
    [setTaskCards]
  );
```

Task.d.ts

```
export type TaskItem = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  group: string;
};
export type TaskColumn = {
  groupID: string;
  groupName: string;
  list: TaskItem[];
};

export type TaskItemForDrag = TaskItem & { index: number };

export type Tasks = {
  tasks: TaskCard[];
};
```

I checked to see if setState was activated when the drag-drop was executed, and sure enough, it was activated and the list was updated. However, only the index was not updated.